# Vue.js 2, change data from directive

Tags: javascript, properties, vue.js, directive, vue-component

Using single file components, how can I change a data property from a directive?

So for example, I've got...

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            is_loading: true
        }
    },
    directives: {
        do_something: {
            bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
                // Change the is_loading property
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought I could do `this.is_loading = false` but `this` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To refer to `this` in a directive you can simply use `vnode.context`, so in you directive you would have:

```
    do_something: {
        bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
            // same as this.is_loading in a directive
            vnode.context.is_loading = false;
        }
    }
```

Then in your markup you would do:

```
<div v-do_domething></div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3qvtdgyd/

Comment: The docs say to treat everything but 'el' as read only.

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hmm. I would argue that this isn't a modification in the sense that the docs are referring to, it's just a reference to the Vue instance, exactly the same as referencing a vue instance from outside the instance itself.